# UISegmentedControl - altering height in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, height, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm creating a number of static custom `UITableViewCells` and have dragged a `UISegmentedControl` onto one of the custom cells.

Whilst the segmented control allows me to alter its width I cannot alter its height in Interface Builder (that property is greyed out on 44 in the 'size' section of the property inspector).

I know that a `UISegmentedControl` can be crated with a custom height in code and added to a UITableViewCell. Is there any way to adjust the height of the segmented control in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it must be done in code. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135407/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-height-of-a-uitoolbar/)

Answer (score 39):

You can also open the `xib` file in any text editor, like Dashcode or MacVim or TextEdit - it's an XML. Then find your element there, in my case it looked like:

```
<object class="IBUISegmentedControl" id="270020637">
    [...]
    <string key="NSFrame">{{20, 154}, {176, 44}}</string>
    [...]
</object>
```

Then you can change the `44` into whatever height you want - you'll see the changes in IB.

This works for all elements that can't be changed height in IB - `UIPicker` also...

Comment: Very nice. Now blame apple for not letting us modify it in IB in the first place

Comment: Awesome answer! Apple fails!

Comment: #highqualityanswer This was the only solution that worked for me on Xcode 5.1 Thanks!

Comment: you can also right click on the .xib in your project listing and select "open as" then select "source code"

Answer (score 35):

You can indirectly change it when you pin the "Height" in Interface Builder (select the segment control then via the menu select `Editor -> Pin-> Height`).

This will add a new Height constraint to the list of constraints for that control which you can then edit. Changes directly reflect in InterfaceBuilder as you can see in the Screenshot below.

[image: interface builder height constraint]

Comment: Great help.  Thanks.  Yes iOS6 only, but as of Feb 2013, that was 83% of iOS devices.  http://www.tuaw.com/2013/02/13/chitika-all-versions-of-ios-6-now-account-for-83-1-of-ios-traf/

Comment: When it's embeded in navigation bar, seems we can't change.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure in IB, but you could always find the cell in your code and programmatically adjust its UISegmentedControl's height.

Answer (score 2):

To do it inside Interface Builder you can select the control and add frame attribute under "User Defined Runtime Attributes"

[image: add frame attribute inside interface builder]

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to Kender's answer.

If you use storyboard rather than XIB, you will need to add:

```
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="10" id="9Wo-6S-8EM"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="201" id="lw7-cq-3XN"/>
```

The id can be anything unique I guess. Maybe pick some ID and modify one letter?

This is the full code

```
<segmentedControl opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="top" segmentControlStyle="plain" selectedSegmentIndex="0" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RMR-XS-abw" userLabel="ngentot2">
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="10" id="9Wo-6S-8EM"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="201" id="lw7-cq-3XN"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <segments>
                            <segment title="First"/>
                            <segment title="Second"/>
                        </segments>
                    </segmentedControl>
```

I add a userLabel so I can easily find the stuff.

Note: reading the storyboard is very enlightening.
Changing storyboard file is VERY dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

We can set autolayout and then set height, After that we can off autolayout. so It will help for other then ios 6.0 .