# UIBarButton Background Image Display Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, image, background, uitoolbar

I added a UIToolBar to a UIViewController and added UIBarButton in it, and also added code for display image in background but image is not displayed

here is my code

```
UIBarButtonItem *b1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"   Home   " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(home: )];
[b1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b1image.png"]];

UIBarButtonItem *b3=[[    UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"   WorkOuts   " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
[b1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b3image.png"]];

UIBarButtonItem *b4=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"   All Exercises  " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(all:)];
[b1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b4image.png"]];

NSArray *li=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:b1,b3,b4, nil];

self.toolBar.items=li;
```

Comment: You should create your `UIBarButtonItem` with `initWithImage:style:target:action:`.

Comment: i try this but white image insted of real image coming

Comment: please is it possible to set bacgrpnd image in UIBarButtonItem ,please help  Desdenova

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `UIBarButtonItem`

You can use a UIButton to display the image:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b1image"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(home:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *b1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

This should fix your problem and set the image correctly. `setImage:` is inherited from another class and will have no affect on `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: please one more thing what size of image i put

Comment: i try image not coming to background please

Comment: Usually `UIToolbar` has a height of 44px so I would recommend a height of 30 px and size depends on what you would like to display. You can even change the size of the toolbar completely to fit your needs. @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135407/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-height-of-a-uitoolbar

Comment: `setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` will not work for `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: It will but the proper way for `UIBarButtonItem` is `initWithImage:style:target:action:`

Comment: And what about the needed title?